# What is the difference between an Icon and an Image in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

What is the difference between an Icon and an Image in Android Jetpack Compose? Is the `Icon` used for vector images, and the `Image` for bitmaps?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[`Icon`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Icon(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.ImageVector,kotlin.String,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color)) is part of [Material design](https://material.io/design/iconography/system-icons.html). So it has default size of `24.dp`, as defined by Material guidelines, and should be used for displaying icons of this size. It'll use `LocalContentColor` value for image tint - if you're using material components, like `Card`, they'll provide it according to the current material theme or overridden component parameters. Or you can change it manually with the `tint` parameter.

Most common usage is using it with predefined material icons, like this:

```kotlin
Icon(
    Icons.Default.Hub,
    contentDescription = "...",
    tint = Color.Black
)
```

But you can create your own icons in code too, check out source code of any default icon for the reference. You can also use it for displaying a resource icon or drawable, they're gonna be scaled to fit.

`Image` is a Compose container for displaying images of any kind. It's much more flexible, like you can set `contentScale`, `colorFilter`, and `alignment`.

Comment: As you pointed out `Icon` use `LocalContentColor` by default so for example if you use it inside a Material design `Card` it'll get the color you specify on `CardColors` 'contentColor' field. It's worth to mention such a nice feature.

Answer (score 2):

Icon and Images can both accept a Vector or BitMap as illustrated below.

**Image**

[image]

**Icon**

[image]

The only difference that I can point to is that Icons use tint to modify the content.