# WearOS Icon from Bitmap doesn't display color

Tags: android, wear-os, android-bitmap

I have a Compose layout that creates a Bitmap/Canvas and draws two colored rectangles to it. However, when drawn (both on an emulator and an actual device), the rectangles show as white.

Here's the code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun WearApp() {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

    val red = Paint()
    red.color = Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)
    canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, 40f, 40f, red)

    val blue = Paint()
    blue.color = Color.BLUE
    canvas.drawRect(60f, 60f, 100f, 100f, blue)

    IconReproTheme {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(24.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        ) {
            Icon(bitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap(),
                contentDescription = null)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the result:
[image: WearOS emulator displaying two white rectangles]

Full code can be [found here](https://github.com/PEConn/IconRepro). How do I get colors to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Image` instead of `Icon`. Icon applies a tint to the shape of the image.

Roughly related answer [What is the difference between an Icon and an Image in Android Jetpack Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69349400/what-is-the-difference-between-an-icon-and-an-image-in-android-jetpack-compose)